# How to implement Short-Circuit evaluation in user-defined functions?

Tags: c++, short-circuiting

Some operators such as `&&` and `||` perform short-circuit evaluation. Also, when a function is called with arguments, all arguments are constructed before calling the function.

For instance, take the following three functions

```
bool f1();
bool f2();
bool f3(bool, bool);
```

if I call

```
if( f3(f2(),f1()) )//Do something
```

Then the return value of both `f2` and `f1` are evaluated before `f3` is called. *But*,  if I had used (the regular) `operator||` instead of `f3`, than the code above would be equivalent to

```
if( f2()||f1() )//Do something
```

and `f1` won't be evaluated if `f2` evaluates to true.

**My question is:** is it possible to have `f3` (a user defined function taking two booleans) behave the same way? If not, what makes the `operator||` so special?

Comment: Might be possible if you inline it... otherwise, absolutely not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if f3() takes the values of the result of the functions.

But if it takes the address of the functions (or more generically treats its input as functors) rather than the results then f3() can decide if it needs to call the function.

```
template<typename F1, typename F2>
bool f3(F1 const& f1, F2 const& f2)
{
    return f1() || f2();
}

bool f1();
bool f2();

int main()
{
    f3(&f1, &f2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is incorrect.  Overloaded `operator||` and `operator&&` always evaluate *both* their arguments; there is no short-circuiting.

See Item 7 of [*More Effective C++*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/More-Effective-Programs-Professional-Computing/dp/020163371X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1330045281&sr=1-1) for a discussion on this.

Comment: I know they do. I'm not talking about overloaded `operator||` I'm talking about the default `operator||`. I'm saying: `operator||` takes 2 arguments but uses short circuiting, is it possible to have the same effect on a user defined function of 2 arguments?

Comment: @BruceConnor: Ah ok.  In that case, the answer is: `operator||` and `operator&&` on primitives are special because the standard says so.  I don't think there's a way to emulate this with arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare || operator and functions like that. || is logical operator and it checks given values, if left operand evaluated to false, then it's no need to check right one.

In case of functions, any value that f1() or f2() return is valid for f3(). There is no way to enable "logical operand" feature for function parameters, even if they take bool parameters.